# Tooltip missing some controls?

Tags: .net, vb.net, controls

Today my project starts a weird behaviour: some controls show the TOOLTIP message and some other no.

For instance, I have 10 buttons in my form and, until some days ago, all Tooltip messages had been appearing normally.

Today I note that some buttons show the message and other does not!

All controls are EQUAL in the Tooltip field, all of them shows the "Tooltip on Tooltip1" (Tooltip1 is the Tooltip control added to the form), all messages are unchanged, and so forth.

I set all messages into controls using the default instruction:

```
ToolTip1.SetToolTip(Me.btnLogIn, Message(n))
```

where `Message(n)` is my array of messages.

So, WHY this strange behaviour? Why some butttons (and everytime the same buttons) shows the message while other does not? The buttons that show the message are neither the first nor the last of LOAD event! And everything was functioning normally, until today.

I´m using VB.NET in VS 2013.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If this happens in debug mode.. try delete the contents of the debug folder ... you will find it in the bin folder

Comment: The problem is occurring either in DEBUG mode as in the EXE created by RELEASE build. it´s amazing!